# If A has a ball and B has a ball

Tags: plural-forms

If A has one ball and B has one ball, isn't just a sentence 'we have two balls' appropriate to combine two situations? I heard of saying 'we are the one,' not 'we are the ones, so I'm confused.

Comment: What is the context for "we are the one" which sounds incorrect in most contexts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is perfectly clear and correct.  "We" = you and I  "have two balls" (one each)

If you mean "I have two balls" and "you have two balls" then "We have two balls each"  (so "We have four balls between us").  And there is never any confusion in a real situation.

But think about your native language.  If you and a friend arrange to meet at a local park.  And you decide to bring a ball.  And when you arrive at the park you see that your friend also has a ball... What do you say (in your native language)?

I bet it isn't the translation of "We have two balls".

You might say "We are one" to mean "you and I together make one team".  It is rather poetic in style.

That is unrelated in meaning to "We are ones" which doesn't seem to mean anything.  (I suppose if a teacher gives every member of their class a number 1 or a number 2 and then says, 'All the ones, stand up' then they could say "We are the ones".  But do you see how odd this context is?  It isn't normal English speaking situation)

You might say "We have one each".  But not "We are one each"

Comment: So, 'we are the one each' is a correct expression!

Comment: No, I shall edit....

Comment: Please can you give an actual real context in which you want to use English.  Languages only make sense when there is something to communicate.

Comment: In addition, red and green apples can mean red apple and green apple?

Comment: Please give an actual example of what you want to say..  Not theoretical. What fact do you want to communicate. And accept that what you *can* say and what you *should* say might be different.

Comment: Sorry............

Answer (score 0):

> If A has one ball and B has one ball, isn't just a sentence 'We have
> two balls' appropriate to combine two situations?

I disagree with @James K. The grammar is correct but the meaning is ambiguous. This is especially the case if two men are speaking because "balls" is slang for "testicles".

To be absolutely clear, you have to differentiate the cases.

**Case 1: There are two people and four balls**

*We each have two balls.*  (Without further context, most people will interpret this to mean that you are both male and each has two testicles)

**Case 2: There are two people and two balls**

*We have a ball each*

*We each have one ball*

---

**EDIT**

The phrase "we are the one" doesn't make sense. It is incorrect unless perhaps said by the Christian God when referring to the Father, Son and Holy Ghost - the holy trinity.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why the downvote? I got some advice with this post.

Comment: I think someone was jealous of you, so downvoted you

Comment: Okay. No worries!